# What is this theme and color scheme

Tags: themes, phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

Simple question... what is both the theme (e.g. panels, sidebar etc.) and the code color scheme used by PhpStorm in the attached screenshot?

[image: screenshot of IDE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ["Afterglow Theme" 3rd-party plugin](https://github.com/JustSid/AfterglowIntelliJ) - you can install it via Settings\Preferences | Plugins | Browse repositories.
Scheme also seems to be [3rd-party Afterglow variation](https://github.com/boneskull/jetbrains-afterglow-scheme).